# SQL different condition multi select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

What I want to do (for each flight), is to select Flight_number, Departure_airport' s **Name** And Arrival_airport' s **Name** . Departure has MIN Leg_number, Arrival has MAX Leg_number.

I have tried this. But join parts or what else missing, here is the link:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/263a2/5

Comment: You are using the same column 'Leg_number' from Flight_leg to to join on max and min leg numbers from ln, that wont work?

Comment: i need to find Departure_airport_code(MIN leg number) and Arrival_airport_code(MAX leg number) and after that join with AIRPORT table.

Comment: So you first need the Air port codes for the (min and max leg numbers) for a particular flight number and then get Airport info based on those codes. Correct?

Comment: Yes, for each flight min(departure) and max(arrival) leg numbers' departments' names and flight number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems odd.. but this might be what you're after...
We get the min/max leg for each flight in subquery aliased "Z"
We use this to join back to flight_leg twice, once for departure and once for arrivals
and again join back twice to airport once for departures once for arrivals.

```
 SELECT Z.Flight_Number, DA.Name DeptName, AA.Name ArrivName
    FROM (SELECT MIN(Leg_Number) MLN, MAX(Leg_Number) MxLN, Flight_Number
               FROM Flight_Leg Group by Flight_Number) Z
    INNER JOIN Flight_Leg D
     on D.Flight_Number = Z.Flight_Number 
    and D.Leg_Number = Z.MLN
    INNER JOIN Flight_Leg A
     on A.Flight_Number = Z.Flight_Number
     and A.Leg_Number = Z.MxLN
    INNER JOIN AirPort DA
     on DA.AirPort_Code = D.Departure_AirPort_Code
    INNER JOIN AirPort AA
     on AA.AirPort_Code = A.Arrival_AirPort_Code
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/263a2/56

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is what you're after. It's written in MS SQL so the syntax will need some minor tweaks.

```
SELECT fl.Flight_number,
ao.Name,
ai.Name,
(select min(Leg_number) from FLIGHT_LEG fa where fl.Flight_number
    = fa.Flight_number) as min_leg_number,

(select max(Leg_number) from FLIGHT_LEG fb where fl.Flight_number
    = fb.Flight_number) as max_leg_number
FROM Flight_leg Fl
inner join AIRPORT as ao on fl.Departure_airport_code =
    ao.Airport_code
inner join AIRPORT as ai on fl.Arrival_airport_code =
    ai.Airport_code
```

Comment: that is the same but i need 2 row for 2 flight here is the link :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99429/1

Comment: that is a syntax problem ?

Comment: There is only 1 row for flight_number 1 because the airport code 'CCC' is not valid, so the inner join throws it away. Change to a left join.

Comment: If you can provide the results set that you're looking for then this will help.